# Output value of puts in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, console

I'm probably missing something really obvious here. I have the following Ruby method:

```
def pair_array

  return self.pair.each_slice(2) {
    |x| puts x.join(" & ")
  }.to_s
end
```

When I try to display the value of this method in my Rails view by calling @team.pair_array nothing appears, but the correct value gets printed on the console. I know this is probably because I'm using puts. How can I get the result of this method to display in my view?

Comment: If you want to return joining each slice then don't use puts; you'd want to collect the output.

Comment: @DaveNewton how do I collect the output? I tried saving it to a variable but that didn't seem to work

Comment: just take off the "puts" (puts is a method to write in the logger, without the "puts", the instruction "x.join('&')" will return a String)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing printing with returning a value. `puts` returns nil, and `each_slice` does not return the result of the block anyway. What you want is this:

```
def pair_array
  pair.each_slice(2).map {|arr| arr.join ' & '}
end
```